# Publishing mongodb references

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Hey I am trying to fetch all the referenced documents in another document and publish them alongside

The skills array in the character collection:

```
skills: [
            _id: 's001'
          ,
            _id: 's002'
          ,
            _id: 's003'
          ,
            _id: 's004'
          ]
```

The publication

```
Meteor.publish 'character', ->
    if this.userId is null
        return

    return [
        Characters.find(userId: this.userId),
        Souls.find(userId: this.userId),
        Items.find(userId: this.userId),
        Skills.find(_id: { $in: 
            Characters.findOne(userId: this.userId).skills
        })
    ]
```

But this doesn't quite work, any advice?

Comment: User separate publish and call from client those individually,
like 
publish("firs",function(userId){})
publish("second",function(userId){})
and then on client
subscribe("firs");subscribe("second")

Comment: but isnt there a smart way to do it using a single publish?

Comment: What about this “doesn’t quite work”? It would be improved by checking to make sure `Characters.findOne` doesn’t return null, but assuming it always finds one document and that document always has a `skills` array, what error or unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: well, I haven't tried it before,
I have many publish and subscribe in my app.